# Bs4 and requests proxy script isn't pulling data

Tags: python, proxy, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-2.x

I am currently working on a script that is supposed to pull some info from supremenewyork.com. The script works on pulling the info from supreme us (the local website) but I want it to pull the same info from the uk website and so I added a proxy script (which I know works because I tested it on a smaller more simple script and it was able to pull information from the uk website that didn't exist on the us website. Anyways here is my script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# make sure proxy is http and port 8080
UK_Proxy1 = raw_input('UK http Proxy1: ')
UK_Proxy2 = raw_input('UK http Proxy2: ')

proxies = {
 'http': 'http://' + UK_Proxy1 + '',
   'https': 'http://' + UK_Proxy2 + '',

}

categorys = ['jackets','shirts','tops_sweaters','sweatshirts','pants','shorts','t-shirts','hats','bags','accessories','shoes','skate']
catNumb = 0

for cat in categorys:
    catStr = str(categorys[catNumb])
    cUrl = 'http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/' + catStr
    proxy_script = requests.get(cUrl, proxies=proxies).text
    bSoup = BeautifulSoup(proxy_script, 'lxml')
    print('\n*******************"'+ catStr.upper() + '"*******************\n')
catNumb += 1
for item in bSoup.find_all('div', class_='inner-article'):
    url = item.a['href']
    alt = item.find('img')['alt']
    req = requests.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com' + url)
    item_soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
    name = item_soup.find('h1', itemprop='name').text
    style = item_soup.find('p', itemprop='model').text
    print alt +(' --- ')+ name +(' --- ')+ style
```

When I run this script all it does is print the categorys but no info between them. For example: ******jackets********, *****shirts*****, etc. I also tested this script in a different way by only pulling info from the accessories category (where the info is different than the us website):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

UK_Proxy1 = raw_input('UK http Proxy1: ')
UK_Proxy2 = raw_input('UK http Proxy2: ')

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://' + UK_Proxy1 + '',
        'https': 'http://' + UK_Proxy2 + '',

}

r10 = requests.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/accessories', proxies=proxies)

soup10 = BeautifulSoup(r10.text, 'lxml')

for item in soup10.find_all('div', class_='inner-article'):
    url = item.a['href']
    alt = item.find('img')['alt']
    req = requests.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com' + url)
    item_soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
    name = item_soup.find('h1', itemprop='name').text
    style = item_soup.find('p', itemprop='model').text
    print alt +(' --- ')+ name +(' --- ')+ style
```

When I run the script above all it does is just go to the next command entry thing right away >>> in the terminal. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: So to recreate your problem what needs to be entered for the two proxies?

Answer (score 0):

Testing without the proxies showed that your indenting needs fixing:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

categorys = ['jackets','shirts','tops_sweaters','sweatshirts','pants','shorts','t-shirts','hats','bags','accessories','shoes','skate']

for catStr in categorys:
    cUrl = 'http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/' + catStr
    proxy_script = requests.get(cUrl).text
    bSoup = BeautifulSoup(proxy_script, 'lxml')
    print '\n*******************"{}"*******************\n'.format(catStr.upper())

    for item in bSoup.find_all('div', class_='inner-article'):
        url = item.a['href']
        alt = item.find('img')['alt']
        req = requests.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com' + url)
        item_soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
        name = item_soup.find('h1', itemprop='name').text
        style = item_soup.find('p', itemprop='model').text
        print u'{} --- {} --- {}'.format(alt, name, style)
```

This produced output for each of your categories:

```
*******************"JACKETS"*******************

Micep6hveho --- S﻿up﻿re﻿m﻿e®/U﻿NDERCOVER/Public Enemy T﻿a﻿ped S﻿e﻿am Pa﻿rka --- Multi﻿
Cl x 5vuuu4 --- Supreme®/U﻿ND﻿E﻿RC﻿OVER/Publi﻿c ﻿E﻿nemy ﻿P﻿uff﻿y Jacket --- Multi
3ez mg0uszy --- Su﻿preme﻿®﻿/UN﻿DERCO﻿VER/P﻿u﻿blic En﻿emy ﻿Work ﻿J﻿ac﻿ket --- Dus﻿ty Teal
Vywmx4joolc --- Su﻿preme﻿®﻿/UND﻿ER﻿COVER/Pu﻿bl﻿ic En﻿emy Wo﻿rk ﻿Jacket --- Bla﻿ck
A8fft p1ixi --- T﻿i﻿ger﻿ Stri﻿pe ﻿Tr﻿ack﻿ ﻿Jacket﻿ --- Brow﻿n﻿
Bxvxpc8 dng --- Tiger Stri﻿pe Track﻿ Jacket --- Whi﻿te

*******************"SHIRTS"*******************

L ktbqa0olk --- Supr﻿em﻿e®/UNDERCOVER﻿/﻿Publ﻿ic Enemy﻿ Ra﻿yo﻿n S﻿hirt --- Red
Wl0es6ehmlc --- S﻿up﻿r﻿em﻿e®﻿/﻿UNDERCOVER/Public E﻿n﻿e﻿my ﻿R﻿a﻿yo﻿n﻿ Shi﻿rt --- Blac﻿k
Qcpiswrgv0q --- Sup﻿r﻿eme®/﻿UN﻿D﻿ERCOV﻿E﻿R/﻿Pu﻿bli﻿c﻿ E﻿nemy ﻿Ray﻿on Shirt --- Green
Cxa3m57wswk --- Deni﻿m S﻿hirt --- Blue
```